# Crawling recursively with import.io

Tags: import.io

I want to crawl all the links, sub-links and so on, that live inside a page (recursively).

Is there a **recursive** option in import.io? If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us more about the specific use case? What site / sub section are you trying to extract data from?

Based on your questions, you may want to check out the "Chain APIs" feature. 
Essentially it allows you to have an API that extracts a set of links, and feed that set into a second API that extracts sub links.

http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/629686-chain-apis-combine-two-apis